# Does there exist an L-system for the sierpiński curve

Tags: geometry, algorithms, formal-languages, fractals

I was going through a list of space-filling fractals and their L-systems. Even though there is an L-system for the sierpiński arrowhead curve, I am unable to find an L-system for the sierpiński curve. Is there any L-system for this? The curve I am referring to is this: [image]

edit: 
An L-system or Lindenmayer system is a parallel rewriting system and a type of formal grammar. An L-system consists of an alphabet of symbols that can be used to make strings, a collection of production rules that expand each symbol into some larger string of symbols, an initial "axiom" string from which to begin construction, and a mechanism for translating the generated strings into geometric structures.

For example, Each order of Hilbert curve can be obtained using the L-system as given below

Alphabet : A, B

Constants : F + −

Axiom : A

Production rules:

A → − B F + A F A + F B −

B → + A F − B F B − F A +

"F" means "draw forward", "−" means "turn left 90°", "+" means "turn right 90°" and "A" and "B" are ignored during drawing. Commonly Turtle graphics is used to draw the curve

Comment: What's an L-system? Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960), and especially the final bullet point, for suggestions regarding definitions. The first comment below that answer is also very good advice regarding definitions.

Comment: The answer to your question is almost certainly "yes."  However, your question does not provide enough context to be sure.  As Lee Mosher suggests, please define what you mean by an "L-system".  Also, I am not sure what curve you are talking about---the Sierpinski arrowhead curve is, to my knowledge, a curve which limits to the Sierpinski gasket, while the curve you have shown in your post is a different curve, which, to my knowledge, is simply called the Sierpinski curve.

Comment: @LeeMosher I have added a basic description of the L-system. Yes, I am talking about the L-system for the Sierpinski curve only, not the arrowhead curve. L-system for the arrowhead curve was available online but I am not able to find the L-system for the Sierpinski curve. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axiom : F--XF--F--XF

Rule : X -> XF+F+XF--F--XF+F+X

Angle : 45

I too was surprised not to be able to find an L-system encoding of this famous curve. I made this one by moding the code for the Square Sierpinski curve.

The curve is usually shown with 2 different edge lengths but I guess that's just aesthetics.

Comment: This works perfectly. Additionally, by changing the '+F+' to '+G+' where G represents forward with different length, I was able to create distinct Sierpinski curves with a different edge length. Thank you :)